# Deleting data from an Excel spreadsheet using SAS

Tags: excel, sas

I have a problem which seemed simple. Although I looked around for a solution here and on internet in general and tried a couple of things that should have solved the problem, nothing works.

I have exported from SAS to Excel using this code:

```
libname xls excel '..\Test3.xlsx' scan_text = no ver=2007;

proc datasets lib = xls nolist;
   delete Sweden;
quit;

data xls.Sweden;
   set WORK.falcon_cases_2;
run;

libname xls clear;
```

And then append another table using this code:

```
libname xls excel '..\Test3.xlsx' scan_text = no ver=2007 ;

proc append base = xls.Sweden
            data = WORK.falcon_cases_NorDen_2;
run;

libname xls clear;
```

I have to do it like this as the data for the two tables comes from different SAS server data tables.

The problem is that this part,

```
proc datasets lib = xls nolist;
   delete Sweden;
quit;
```

only deletes the named range which only extends to the first data set put into the spreadsheet. So if the first table is 10 rows and the second 15, adding up to 25 rows in the spreadsheet. When delete is done, only the first 10 rows have been cleared.
I've tried using

```
proc sql noprint; 
   drop table xls.'Sweden$'n;
quit;
```

but the result is the same. Both solutions seem to be limited to only clear data within the named range.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The last two `proc datasets` steps are identical

Comment: Can you append the datasets together to a single SAS dataset prior to exporting to excel?

Comment: Unfortunately no since that would have been ideal.

Comment: Thanks mjsqu. I edited the post with the other code now.

Comment: Then you may need to use excel commands through DDE or a VB script or similar to delete the tab.  Sheet and Range are identical in concept to SAS, and with SAS creating the sheet initially, you seem to be stuck.  You might consider opening up a ticket with SAS Support and seeing if they have a workaround or if it's changed in a later version.

Comment: So.. If SAS isn't creating the sheet. I have an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Joe - your latest comment gave me an idea. If I combine export methods it seems to be possible to work around the issue. I exported the first table using

```
PROC EXPORT DATA= WORK.falcon_cases_2
OUTFILE= "..\Test3.xlsx" 
DBMS=XLSX REPLACE;
SHEET="Sheet1"; 
RUN;
```

and then appended the second table using the same append code as earlier. So the next time PROC EXPORT runs, it replaces everything and thus fixing my problem :)